# Performance Array of Views that change fast for Animation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a performance issue.
I have an array full of Paths (struct with path and id) that change 60 times per seconds because of a step from the CADisplayLink. I am appending one new Path at the front and remove one Path at the end of that array.

In the view there would be something like this:

```
ForEach(arr,id: \.id){
   $0.path
}
```

The problem is that if there are 600 items in that array the animation begins to slow down.
A different approach was to use a uiimagerenderer, which is fast at the desktop but not at an older real iPhone anymore. Should i loop through this array in the imagerenderer or is there any option in swiftui to use the Array full of views with good performance also with many views inside?
Thanks for an answer.

Comment: You should iterate through data and put it in a `View` not have a huge array of `View`s. SwiftUI doesn't do well when there are many `View`s there are many SO questions that talk about a `List` with simple images running slow and having to revert to `UIKit` for large datasets

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Is there a solution, that I don’t have to iterate through all the elements because all elements in the middle of that array will stay in the frame. There is only the first item which is added and the last should be removed, so there is only a change of 2 items per frame. If I iterate through all, I always have to calculate all positions and a test with an iPhone 6s was not Good, because the frame rate dropped.